# SemanticImport adds garbage characters to key name

Tags: import, dataset

I want to import a csv to a dataset. This exact dataset successfully imported on a PC, but on a Mac one of the columns has garbage characters added to the key (see below example). I don't believe these characters are in the csv--regular "Import" doesn't show them. At least one other csv SemanticImport doesn't do this. If I rename the key, the characters remain. If I delete the leftmost column, the new key for the leftmost column gets these characters. So:

1. What is causing this?
2. Can I systematically avoid this issue? (I can probably think of a bandaid for this situation, but if this happens with any frequency this is a terrible roadblock to my workflow.)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding setting `CharacterEncoding` to something? Maybe it's to do with that.

Comment: That looks like the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that is put at the beginning of an UTF-8 encoded file - not sure why `SemanticImport` fails to recognize that though. What Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: Ok, I've just checked it on MacOS with Mathematica 11.3 and I can reproduce the issue (not on Windows, same as OP) - you can fix it by adding `CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"` as option to `SemanticImport`. Please also report this to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback), since this is clearly a deficit of `SemanticImport` on MacOS

Comment: @LukasLang I am using Mathematica 12.0. Thanks for the bug fix in the mean time, works very well.